# How to get a script to give a value to an input prompt?

Tags: matlab

I have a collection of smaller scripts `foo1`, `foo2`, etc. and a script `master.m` that runs them all, like this:

```
% master.m

run foo1

run foo2
```

Let's say `foo1` calls for input somewhere by saying `a = input('Gimme a number\n');`.

I thought that if I put the value(s) I wanted on new lines after the `run` command that they would be entered as input, but they don't. I've also tried enclosing them as a string, i.e. `'5'`. That doesn't work either.

Is their another function I should use? I looked at the help file for `input`, but there's no `output` function. Presumably there's something like `write` or `writetostdio` somewhere.

How do I give user input to a script that is being called by another script without touching the keyboard? Can I put the values I want to input in the `master.m` file?

EDIT:
Because there's some confusion, I'll try to clear it up.

The scripts `foo1` and `foo2` will NOT be passing values back and forth. Every script will be `run` independently. Instead, I'm trying to test a *program* for a range of user behaviours (which are responses to prompts via `input` in `foo1`). These are normally typed on the keyboard, but I want my `master.m` file to tell `foo1` what the user inputs are.

Sorry if this is confusing, but hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: Use [functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Comment: Each script is already a whole program that calls a bunch of other functions. Although it would be technically possible to change them all into functions, that wouldn't be a very "nice" solution (takes a lot of time, means that previous whole programs are now functions, there's a chance that I'll break something...). The idea of the master script is that I can run it and then come back in the morning to see the results.

Comment: Functions have defined inputs and outputs, it's their purpose. Scripts don't. Laziness is not an excuse to look for a poor programming solution. This is asking for a poor programming solution. Using functions does not prohibit running one thing and coming back in the morning to see results.

Comment: Converting the scripts to functions doesn't make sense here. He wants to run a testing script that runs another script which asks a user input. In production the script will always ask the input to come from keyboard so it doesn't make sense to make it a function to accept parameters. However for testing purposes wants to run it automatically providing the inputs so he can test a bunch of input values. So again, the suggestion of converting the script to a function does not make sense.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The conclusion you draw from that premise is nonsensical. A well defined function that takes inputs from a wrapper prompting for user input makes far more sense than any kludged solution that tries to pipe values because this *also* accommodates batched/automated calls. He wants to take the output from a script and use it as an input to another script. [That's a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test).

Comment: Actually, what @SembeiNorimaki is saying is what I want to do.

I have a program that takes inputs from the user.
I want to see what happens for particular sets of inputs (this is a test).
I want to see how the program reacted after those inputs.
I want to do this for something like 50 sets of test inputs.

This is not unit testing for functions, but rather trying to generate data from complete programs for ranges of values.

If this is not possible for whatever reason, I can live with that. But I would like to know either way.

Comment: If `foo2` needs to get the *output* of `foo1` as *input*, then `foo1` and `foo2` need to be functions.

Comment: @AnderBiguri That is not the case. 

`foo1` is a script (a complete program with `main.m` and associated functions) that requires some user input (say, number of iterations). 

I want to see what outputs I get for a range of iterations. (Does my approximation get better if I double the number of iterations? etc.)

I won't be passing the output (which is printed to the console; it also produces a figure) to any other script.

Comment: To reiterate, the scripts are not passing values between each other. I am just running them sequentially and trying to give user input to one/some of them.

Comment: In `foo1` does not have inputs, you can not give them from `master`, as giving values from `master` is the whole points of *inputs*

Answer (score 4):

Modifying existing code to accommodate both manual input and testing inputs is trivial:

```
function foo1(niterations)
if nargin == 0
    niterations = round(input('How many iterations? '));
end

for ii = 1:numel(niterations)
    % Run the thing
    fprintf('Running some random program with %d iterations! Yay!\n', niterations(ii));
end

end
```

Using this approach we can do:

```
>> foo1
How many iterations? 2
Running some random program with 2 iterations! Yay!
```

or

```
>> foo1(2)
Running some random program with 2 iterations! Yay!
```

or

```
>> foo1([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
Running some random program with 1 iterations! Yay!
Running some random program with 3 iterations! Yay!
Running some random program with 5 iterations! Yay!
Running some random program with 7 iterations! Yay!
Running some random program with 9 iterations! Yay!
```

This is far more logical than trying to pipe things from text files, use `evalin` to poof things into workspaces, or whatever automagical approach is required to accommodate using scripts in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a bit ugly... but might be a work-around if for some reason `foo1.m` etc. have to remain as scripts.

The idea is to replace each instance of `input` with a newly defined function `myInput` which checks if a variable `PROMPT_VALUE` has been set in the base work-space; and returns that if so, and otherwise passes through to the built-in `input`. For example:

```
% myInput.m
function [ valueOut ] = myInput( promptString )

    W = evalin('caller','whos'); %or 'base'
    doesPVexist = ismember('PROMPT_VALUE',[W(:).name]);

    if doesPVexist
        valueOut = evalin('caller', 'PROMPT_VALUE');
    else
        valueOut = input(promptString);
    end

end
```

Assuming we have the following sub-scripts:

```
% foo1.m
a = myInput('Number to double: ');
disp(2*a);

% foo2.m
b = myInput('Number to halve: ');
disp(b/2);
```

We can test the approach as follows:

```
% master.m
clearvars;
PROMPT_VALUE=5;
run foo1.m;

PROMPT_VALUE=3;
run foo2.m
```

If you run this as-is it will take the PROMPT_VALUE as inputs to each of the subscripts (returning 10, and 1.5). If those lines are commented out it will look for input from the user.

Comment: It's a workaround, but under no circumstances a *helpful* workaround. The helpful solution is to do it differently.

Comment: @Sembei keep in mind that SO is not only here to help the specific asker, it is meant as a knowledge base of programming. One might think that it's more helpful in the long run and for the general public to stop propagating harmful programming practices. Often the proper answer to "*How do I do stupid thing Y to solve X?*" is "*Do non-stupid thing Z instead.*"

Comment: Agree, is more the tone used. If somebody asks a perfectly valid question and the response is: "You are lazy, your programming style sucks and here is my intelligent answer" then probably the OP will not learn much and will not ask again.